# Terraform: Stop printing plan to console when apply or destroy are called

Tags: terraform

I recently upgraded from Terraform 14.9 to 15.4.

In 14.9, I could use the `-auto-approve` option in either the `apply` or `destroy` commands and this would also stop terraform printing its plan to the console window. However, v15.4 no longer does this, instead choosing to output the whole plan. This unnecessary printing slows down the process when deploying a lot of resources and for what I am doing, I dont care what it is telling me.

Therefore, is there a command/option to revert to the 14.9 behaviour so I don't see the plan when apply or destroy are called?

---

EDIT: So the calls I make are as follows:

```
>terraform plan -lock=false -out=tfplan -input=false
```

then

```
>terraform apply -lock=false -input=false tfplan
```

in V15.4 calling the apply command will result in the plan being printed to the console window, which v14.9 did not do.

Note 1: I have also had to add `-lock=false` to stop a locking error that occurs when run in v15.4. Although not ideal, this is *not* on a network shared by other users so is fine for my situation.

Note 2: I did previously have the `-auto-approve` but the new `-input=false`option overrides it. I was following content from the [apply](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html) page and the associated [automation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/automate-terraform?in=terraform/automation&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS) page. But these still result in output being put in the console.

---

Comment: Wow seriously? 15.4 does that? Just curious, if you do a `plan` right before the `apply -auto-approve` does it still show you the plan?

Comment: Are you executing on a config or a binary plan output when you `apply` or `destroy`?

Comment: Mat and Ked, hopefully my updates have answered your questions. (1) Calling plan immediately before unfortunately changes nothing (2) the tfplan file is binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised this issue as a bug with Hashicorp [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28898).

Their response is this was an intentional change because the apply action, in isolation, didn't explain what it was doing. The rationale being the `-auto-approve` should only skip the approval prompt, not the planning phase entirely.

Nonetheless, they are taking my issue into consideration.

Can I also say how pleasant the experience of dealing with Hashicorp has been (they have been very responsive).

All the best